# GTM - fire event to Google Analytics for each element of array

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a question regarding targeting multiple array members via GTM. I push an array to the dataLayer. Is there a way to loop over the array and then push an event for each element of the array to Google Analytics?

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same question, have yet to find a solution. Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, no.